# is it possible to have a function that depends on another function on the same level in python?

Tags: python

I have been trying to create kind of a tree of code out of functions where anywhere in the tree I can call a function and it will follow executing every next function in the line. I keep getting errors saying something like "a is not defined in line 5" in the func2.

```
def func1():
    global a
    a = 2
    func2()
def func2():
    global b
    b = a - 1
    func3()
```

Comment: Well it says things like 'a is not defined' because it is not defined in the respective function (or in a higher scope) ... you defined 'a' in func1 and try to use in in func2. what else is python supposed to do here? it will not guess you that you mean the variable from another function because you can have equal names for parameters in any number of other functions as well.

Comment: It's not that I don't understand, I just have no clue how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you have to define the function before calling it.

---

The code sample bellow produces the error you got.

```py
def func1():
    a = 2
    func2() # <- func2 does not exist yet

def func2():
    b = a - 1
    func3() # <- unless defined above, func3 does not exist either
```

---

Instead, the following code should work

```py
def func3():
    pass

def func2():
    global b
    b = a - 1
    func3() # <- func3 is defined, it will be ok

def func1():
    global a
    a = 2
    func2() # <- func2 is defined too, no problem here

func1()
print(a,b)
```

Comment: It will still raise an error as `a` is not defined in `func2`. It needs to be global.

Comment: Will edit the post to make 'a' a global variable. I have it like that in the code, just forgot to add it here.

Comment: I edited my answer with global variable, and a call to func1 just to test.

Comment: I tried that, but I still get an error even with global variables.

Comment: What version of python are you using ? The code run just fine in 3.7 and 2.7 for me.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a lazy language, in this context it means the existence of functions is not verified during compilation until the code is actually called. You are running into errors at this line :

```
b = a - 1
```

As you are assigning from a variable which is undefined in func2()

The following dcompiles fine :

```
def func1():
    func2()

def func2():
    func3()
```

However if you try calling func1() without defining func3(), you hit an error at runtime as Python realizes that func3() hasn't been defined yet.

In short : The order of definition of functions does not matter as long as they are all defined. This does not mean that you can reference local variables of one function in another. That's not allowed in Python.

Comment: You say you can’t reference local variables within a function, but what if they’re global variables specified by global var

Comment: @JhonConners global vars can be accessed in any function in the same progam and don't require any identifier in Python. In your script, you were trying to access the local variables of one function in another, that's not allowed.